# Remove drive out of the PC

Tags: uninstall, drive

I have a problem that I don't know how to remove my drive (vutung2001) out of the PC. Because it's the school PC, so I don't want anyone see my drive. How can I remove it?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about your ***Google Drive*** or any _physical drive_?

Answer (score 1):

Click the ⏏ icon in the lower left corner of the screenshot next to "vutung2001..." to unmount the drive. Then open the Disks application from the Dash. Select the vutung2001 drive in Disks, and click the  power on/off icon  <kbd>⏻</kbd>  in the top right corner of Disks to power off this disk.